# How can i create a solr core instanceDir inside other location(like /instanceDirectory)?

Tags: java, solr, server

I am using solr 5.3.0 and i need to create a core that have "/instanceDirectory" as its instance directory. Please get the current solr directory tree below:

```
  /opt/solr-5.3.0/

|-- bin
|   `-- init.d
|-- contrib
|  
|-- dist
|   
|-- docs
|   
|-- example
| 
|-- licenses
`-- server
    |-- contexts
    |-- etc
    |-- lib
    |   `-- ext
    |-- logs
    |-- modules
    |-- resources
    |-- scripts
    |   
    |-- solr
    |   |-- configsets
    |   |  
    |   |-- **solrcore1**
    |   |   |-- conf
    |   |   |   `-- lang
    |   |   `-- data
    |   |       |-- index
    |   |       |-- snapshot.20160603081946736
    |   |       |-- snapshot.20160613103014524
    |   |       `-- tlog
    |   |-- **solrcore2**
    |   |   |-- conf
    |   |   |   `-- lang
    |   |   `-- data
    |   |       |-- index
    |   |       |-- snapshot.20160603074933399
    |   |       |-- snapshot.20160603074950692
    |   |       `-- tlog
    |   `-- **solrcore3**
    |       |-- conf
    |       |   `-- lang
    |       `-- data
    |           |-- index
    |           |-- snapshot.20160603062030636
    |           |-- snapshot.20160603074938811
    |           `-- tlog
    |
    `-- solr-webapp
        `-- webapp
            |-- css
            |   |-- angular
            |   `-- styles
            |-- img
            |   |-- filetypes
            |   `-- ico
            |-- js
            |   |-- angular
            |   |   `-- controllers
            |   |-- lib
            |   `-- scripts
            |-- libs
            |-- partials
            |-- tpl
            `-- WEB-INF
                `-- lib
```

I want to have solrcore4 instance directory as "/**solrcore4**" not "/opt/solr-5.3.0/server/solr/solrcore4".

Can anyone help me to make this possible ?

Thanks in ADV.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two levels of configuration:

- Solr home. That's the root of all cores. In your case, it is probably *server/solr*. This can be changed, but will affect all the cores, not just one. You can change it by starting Solr with a different parameter for solr home (depending on your configuration) or by changing [solr.xml file](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Format+of+solr.xml#Formatofsolr.xml-The%3Csolr%3EElement) to point to a different location.
- The other option is to have the core in one place but its changeable (data/index) files in another. This can be done by setting [dataDir property in the core.properties](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Defining+core.properties) file that marks the root of the core. It is also possible to use configSet property to have the config files somewhere else, but that's a bit more gimmicky.